# Some elementary inequality for upper bound

Tags: inequality

Let $a_0,a_1,a_2...$ be nonnegative real number sequence.

Let $t>0,A>0,B>0$ so that

$$a_0 \leq At$$
$$a_{k+1} \leq B t a_k$$

Then 
$$a_{k+1} \leq Bta_k \leq (Bt)^2a_{k-1}...$$

So $$a_{k+1} \leq (Bt)^{k+1}a_0$$

> My Question.
>   Is there $C>0$ so that $$a_{k+1} \leq \frac{Ct^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$$

Could you give me some hint or answer?

Comment: Consider $A=B=2, \: t =\frac 12$ and all $a_k=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<t\leq1$ then the answer is "yes".

If $t>1$ so use the Stirling's approximation.